# how do you make a list of numbers and then arrange them even first then odd?

Tags: python, list, loops

> "I’m a world-renowned fashion designer and I’m about to screen new models for next month’s Fashion Week. I made them all wear different numbers and what I want you to do is separate the even-numbered models from the odd-numbered ones and make sure they get to go first. I don’t care if they call it number discrimination, I just have a preference for even numbers, okay? It’s not weird!"

An example of the output should look like:

```
Enter the number of elements: 4
Element #1: 6
Element #2: 5
Element #3: 17
Element #4: 12

Arranged Elements:
Element #1: 6
Element #2: 12
Element #3: 5
Element #4: 17
```

as you can see the list of elements are arranged, even first, then odd.

This is my current code:

```
num_list = []
listLength = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
num = 1

for i in range(listLength):
  el = int(input("Element #%d: " % num))
  num += 1
    if el % 2 == 0:
        num_list.append(el)
    elif el % 2 != 0::
         num_list.append(el)
print(num_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you keep appending to the same list, whether it is an even or an odd number. You need two lists:

```
even_list = []
odd_list = []
listLength = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
...
```

then:

```
    if el % 2 == 0:
        even_list.append(el)
    elif el % 2 != 0:
        odd_list.append(el)
```

and finally, concatenate the two lists:

```
num_list = even_list + odd_list
print(num_list)
```